# Python Logistic Regression Odds Ratio 0 or 1

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

### Edit:
For which category, 0 or 1 does Python sklearn Logistic Regression by default provides the coefficient and thus the Odds Ratio.

I'm wondering for which category I'm getting my odds ratio in a logistic regression:

Odds ratio:

```
params = model.params
conf = model.conf_int()
conf['Odds Ratio'] = params
conf.columns = ['5%', '95%', 'Odds Ratio']
print(np.exp(conf))
```

So first of if 1 = Yes and 0 = No then:

|  | 5% | 95% | Odds Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| const | 2.497035 | 2.670068 | 2.582102 |
| x1 | 1.110917 | 1.196509 | 1.152919 |
| x2 | 1.185360 | 1.272626 | 1.228218 |
| x3 | 2.424528 | 2.752994 | 2.583546 |
| x4 | 1.067706 | 1.135763 | 1.101209 |
| x5 | 1.259765 | 1.348388 | 1.303323 |
| x6 | 7.104122 | 7.563664 | 7.330293 |

And the other way around, 0=yes, 1=no

|  | 5% | 95% | Odds Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| const | 0.376813 | 0.402834 | 0.389606 |
| x1 | 0.828915 | 0.892628 | 0.860182 |
| x2 | 0.782983 | 0.840419 | 0.811193 |
| x3 | 0.374006 | 0.424037 | 0.398237 |
| x4 | 0.872428 | 0.927973 | 0.899772 |
| x5 | 0.739507 | 0.791352 | 0.764990 |
| x6 | 7.096197 | 7.554404 | 7.321717 |

I'm thinking the odds are for =1, however at least one of the odds where Yes = 1 is not making sense to me based on some natural assumptions of the data, and all the odds ratios below where yes = 0, except the one that doesn't make sense above, also make little sense based on my assumptions of the data; but anyway I'd like some confirmation on the matter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally found my answer:

"Because of the logit function, logistic regression coefficients represent the log odds that an observation is in the target class (“1”) given the values of its X variables."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).